# How do I get the list of button using watin?

Tags: button, web-crawler, watin

How can I use Watin to get the list of available button on a website?
How do the watinTestRecorder do it?

Answer (score 1):

IE ie = new IE("www.example.com/pagewithbuttons.html");

```
ButtonCollection buttons = ie.Buttons;
```

If you want to filter out in visible buttons, use:

```
ButtonCollection buttons = ie.Buttons.Filter(!Find.ByStyle("visible", "none"));
```

HTH,
Jeroen van Menen